# turn off Android screen saver when certain HTTP event

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, display

Good morning,

I am developing a Xamarin.Form application for an always-on tablet.
As desired, the screen saver starts after 30 minutes of inactivity.
The application listens for some events through HTTP.
Upon receiving a particular event, I would need to deactivate the screen saver, thus showing the screen of the active application.
Is there any way I can do this in Xamarin.Form?

Thank you so much

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you Jason for your feedback, however I don't need to prevent the screen saver from appearing, but deactivate it when it has already been activated. The tablet stays on 24/7 with the same interface, so it is correct for me that the screen saver can activate normally

Comment: Note: it doesn’t matter that you are using Xamarin Forms. Any solution to this would be in Android-specific project. (Any answer in java could easily be adapted to c#.) I don’t know the answer, but maybe a different way of approaching it. If the app is in foreground, maybe don’t actually go into screensaver mode, but simulate a screensaver? Is this like a kiosk, where device is always plugged in?